# Azure IoTHub throwing exceptions I cannot catch

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a Xamarin app using the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient to listen for messages from the Azure IoT hub. Occasionally I get errors thrown that I cannot catch, and deal with. One such exception is:

Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.UnauthorizedException

This exception is just an example of an exception I am getting, and one that I can reliably recreate by changing system time. Other IoTHubExceptions are sporadic and difficult to recreate and hence the need to try and catch the exception.

Can anyone tell me how I can catch these IoT hub based errors? The code is:

```
try
{
   await _deviceClientInbound.OpenAsync();

   // execution never gets passed this line and the exception is eventually thrown, having reached this point
   Message receivedMessage = await _deviceClientInbound.ReceiveAsync();

   if (receivedMessage == null) continue;

   await _deviceClientInbound.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   // Exception is never caught in here ...
   // How can I catch the IoTHubException based exceptions
}
```

Comment: Is the function where this code is declared as returning a `Task` or `Task<T>`? Are you also certain it is being thrown from these calls?

Comment: Yes, the signature of the method is "private async Task StartReceiverAsync()", while I can't be 100% sure that it is this call causing the problem. It is the only place I am doing anything IoTHub related and the problem only happens when execution reaches this code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting unauthorized exception . Then please check your iot hub connection string used in device client to confirm that the shared access polity used with connection string have all the privileges or not, that is needed at your end.

Comment: I'm only using the Unauthorized exception as an example here, because I can easily recreate this exception. My problem is that I cannot catch any exception thrown by the IoT hub client in a Xamarin Android app.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with a .net console application or others?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the various refactorings done for the supported platforms and you will likely have to catch all exceptions, process the ones you want, and rethrow ones you don't. Depending on platform you might be able to include:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions;
```

The sources are here if you feel like spelunking:

**https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=using+Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions**